# WPF C# Databind: In C# Change a Control Color when another control is Highlighted

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I'm perplexed on this one.

I want to simply change the COLOR of a specific button if a specific textbox has focus.
Is this possible with databinding in C# or should I use a conventional event trigger with methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use code like this to dynamically generate a button which turns red when the `TextBox` named "txtBox1" has keyboard focus:

```
Style style = new Style { TargetType = typeof(Button) };
DataTrigger trigger = new DataTrigger
    {
        Binding = new Binding("IsKeyboardFocusWithin") { ElementName = "txtBox1" },
        Value = true
    };
trigger.Setters.Add(new Setter { Property = Button.BackgroundProperty,
     Value = Brushes.Red });
style.Triggers.Add(trigger);
Button btn = new Button { Content = "Test button", Style = style };
```

Comment: Yes, I wrote a test program and it worked fine. Did you replace `txtBox1` by the name of your text box, and did you ensure that this name in the same name scope as the button control? Alternatively, try to use [Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.source%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of `ElementName`.

Comment: Thanks, I verified it.

Answer (score 2):

This is definitely possible with data binding.

On your textbox set `IsFocused="{Binding MyTextBoxFocused}"` in your XAML.

Then on your button, set `Background="{Binding MyButtonColor}"` in your XAML.

In your ViewModel, define 2 properties bool MyTextBoxFocused and a Brush MyButtonColor.  Make sure your ViewModel implements from INotifyPropertyChanged.

On the MyTextBoxFocused

```
set 
{ 
MyButtonColor = value ? Color.Red : Color.Blue; 
RaisePropertyChanged("MyButtonColor"); 
RaisePropertyChanged("MyTextBoxFocused"); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mangist, now the UI is dynamically generated so no XAML, can it be all done in C# code?

Comment: I thought you wanted to use databinding (with XAML).  You can do it all in code behind, but as you said, you'll need to use event handlers.